# How to randomly generate a 12 digit hexadecimal where no more than 2 digits repeated?

Tags: c#

I want to generate randomly 12 digit hexadecimal. The constraint is that no more 2 digits are repeated as the whole and no consecutive repetition. How to write the efficient code?

```
xx11xxxxxxxx is not valid because the same digit (e.g., 1) appears consecutively.

12121xxxxxxx is not valid as well because the digit 1 appears thrice.
```

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I will submit my effort soon...

Comment: Does repeated mean consecutive? IOW is `12131` valid? As a first step you could simply generate tokens in a loop until you find one that satisfies your constraints.

Comment: Clarification, when you say "2 digits repeated" - you mean a total of 2 digits? two consecutive repetitions or something else? ie - 111112222 is valid? 112211221122 is valid? 123123123 is valid?

Comment: @knittl: Yes, 2 adjacent digits cannot exist and the same numbers cannot appear more than 2.

Comment: Generate digits one by one, if a digit doesn't match the rule of uniqueness, generate this digit again until it matches. Just a sligtly optimized approach of the straightforward algorithm "generate -> check -> throw away and generate again until matches".

Comment: As soon as you add a constraint such as no more than 2 digits repeated it is not random anymore.

Comment: But `1212345...` is valid?

Comment: You need a *shuffle*, randomly picking 12 digits from a set of 32 hex digits.  Like cards from two decks.  Type "fisher yates" in the Search box.

Answer (score 1):

Create the string var "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF" and then use random generator to mix order of chars and chek if not twice, and the last step is cut it to 12 chars.